# MYSQL table partitions in innodb_sys_tables blocking aws upgrade

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, amazon-rds

I have a table partitioned with DDL like

```
show create table backfill;
CREATE TABLE `backfill` (
  ...
  `entry_date` date NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_date`, ...)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITIONS 731 */
```

This creates a bunch of innodb_sys_tables entries like

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| table_id | name                                                      |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+

| 3132137  | adwords_production/attribution_list_stats_backfill#P#p0    |
```

These entries, in turn, block me from being able to upgrade from mysql 5.7 to mysql 8.0 on aws, resulting in

```
17) Schema inconsistencies resulting from file removal or corruption
Following tables show signs that either table datadir directory or frm file was removed/corrupted. Please check server logs, examine datadir to detect the issue and fix it before upgrade
production - present in INFORMATION_SCHEMA's INNODB_SYS_TABLES table but missing from TABLES table
```

Which research (and AWS' own staff think are because of the `#` characters in the names in the innodb_sys_tables entries.

So. Is it possible to rename the `innodb_sys_tables` entries without breaking the tables themselves, since these all have a  "table_id" that's probably how they're referenced elsewhere?

Or is there a way that I can control the name when we create the partition? If so, is there a way I can use partition tools to rename these tables?

I haven't done much database administration, so I'm not even sure how to run a small experiment to try this myself.

Any pointers would make me eternally grateful.

Comment: How do they suggest the `#` characters got there?  They almost certainly got there because they're supposed to be there, and this is a false detection caused by a defect in the upgrade checking process.  This would, unfortunately, not be the first time I've seen RDS support offer implausible explanations for defects in the platform that they should recognize as such and take responsibility for fixing.  This is almost certainly not your problem, it's theirs.

Comment: I agree, I was just hoping that as names, that are not the primary identifier for the tables, I might be able to change them anyway.